# How come Python is not printing out my other inputs after the first input?

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner to Python and I am trying to make a program that will capitalise or lowercase the user's input.

However, I am running into a problem where Python will print out the first block of lines of user inputs but won't print out the other 2 blocks. I was wondering, was it because of my indentations? I wrote this code on Google Colab if you're curious and want to test it out on there.

I also want the code to stop executing whenever the user inputs q, but I'm not sure if I did it right.

I tried playing around with indentations and rearranging my code around, but unfortunately it did nothing. Here is my code:

```
# user enters inputs
# block 1

input1 = input("Enter a sentence (or use q to quit): ")
if input1 == "q":
  print("The user has aborted the program.")

else:
  input2 = input("Uppercase or Lowercase? (U/L): ")

# display inputs and either does uppercase or lowercase depending on user input


  if (input2 == "U"):
    print("The Uppercase of" + " " + input1 + " " + "is" + " " + input1.upper() + ".")

  elif (input2 == "L"):
    print("The Lowercase of" + " " + input1 + " " + "is" + " " + input1.lower() + ".")




  # user enters inputs
  # block 2

    input3 = input("Enter a sentence (or use q to quit): ")
    if (input3 == "q"):
      print("The user has aborted the program.")

    else:
      input4 = input("Uppercase or Lowercase? (U/L): ")

  # display inputs and either does uppercase or lowercase depending on user input


      if   (input4 == "U"):
          print("The Uppercase of" + " " + input3 + " " + "is" + " " + input3.upper() + ".")

      elif (input4 == "L"):
          print("The Lowercase of" + " " + input3 + " " + "is" + " " + input3.lower() + ".")



 # user enters inputs
 # block 3 

      input5 = input("Enter a sentence (or use q to quit): ")
      if input5 == "q":
        print("The user has aborted the program.")

      else:
        input6 = input("Uppercase or Lowercase? (U/L): ")

      # display inputs and either does uppercase or lowercase depending on user input


      if (input6 == "U"):
          print("The Uppercase of" + " " + input5 + " " + "is" + " " + input5.upper() + ".")

      elif (input6 == "L"):
          print("The Lowercase of" + " " + input5 + " " + "is" + " " + input5.lower() + ".")
```

Comment: You really need better variable names than `input1` through `input29340492304`.

Comment: The way this code keeps nesting more and more deeply is not helping clarity at all. Consider using a loop that calls one or more functions, each of which has *one job*.

Comment: Are you intending this to run inside a loop?

Comment: Hmm, i see, i will try and use a loop. And no, I was not intending for this to run into a loop

Comment: What loop would you recommend?

Comment: Hint: loop while input is not q

Comment: @MarkTolonen I understand what you're trying to say about "loop while input is not q" but I am a little bit lost in how I would "code" that.

Comment: simply printing `print("The user has aborted the program.")` - does not abort the program

Comment: _Python will print out the first block of lines of user inputs but won't print out the other 2 blocks_ Don't make us guess what you mean by "first block" and "other 2 blocks".  Instead, show us the ACTUAL OUTPUT of this program, along with the ACTUAL INPUT that you entered, so we can see exactly what the code did and we don't have to guess!

Comment: @JohnGordon I added comments into my code indicating what the "blocks" are at the start of my code. Sorry if I didn't make it clear in the title.

Comment: block 2 and block 3 are entirely indented underneath `elif (input2 == "L")`, so if input2 is not "L", none of that code will execute.

Comment: @JohnGordon Oh, so should all the code under input2 == L  not be indented? I'll try and play around with it now.

Comment: @JohnGordon So I played around with it and your suggestion did work, my other inputs are now displaying. However, now I am trying to make the program stop executing after the user inputs "q". But when I do input "q" the other inputs still execute.

Comment: As @ScaryWombat commented above, if the user enters "q", the program prints "The user has aborted the program", but it doesn't do anything that would actually abort.  How were you expecting that to work?

Comment: @JohnGordon It is a bit rough, I thought that if the user inputted "q" It would just print "The user has aborted the program" and not the other print statements. I can see that it is very wrong, so I will try and look into other options like others have mentioned such as a loop function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: More generally, please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. It is your responsibility before posting to come up with a *simple* example that *directly demonstrates* the problem; if you don't know how to do this, then you are missing skills that are required to ask suitable questions. At any rate, we don't fix your code here, we answer questions; and we are looking for clear, direct questions that can be of use to others, but which haven't been asked before.

Comment: For the kind of help you seem to be looking for (and need), I **strongly recommend** using an actual discussion forum instead, such as https://reddit.com/r/learnpython or https://discuss.python.org/ .

Answer (score -1):

Your mistake is that Python places great emphasis on *spaces*, and the following two blocks should not have spaces, otherwise they will be executed in the else statement of the first block.

You just need to indent all the code for block2 and block3, and the shortcut key is "Shift+Tab".

Comment: so was it because I used the spacebar for indentation for block 2 and block 3?

Comment: YES, you have got it

Answer (score -2):

You were correct when you mentioned your indentation. Make sure your indentation is consistent for each code block.

I'm not a python developer but I know indentation matters when defining code blocks in python.

I tested out your code in a web compiler and it worked as you intended, having 3 prompts. For exiting / quitting conditions, maybe try playing with the quit() function to exit your prompts, your "if" condition is fine though.

Great to see beginners playing around with coding. Keep up the good work!

Comment: I have tried playing with the quit() function but it still doesn't really "quit" my program, it just continues running.